Translating Householder formulas to the complex case
I'm currently trying to implement a algorithm from Burden's Numerical Analysis described in Chapter 9.4. The algorithm calculates for a given symmetric real matrix $A$ a unitarily equivalent symmetric tridiagonal matrix $T$ without calculating the matrix multiplication explicitly. The derivation of the algorithm is pretty complex and I'm not certain if I did it correctly, but it is mainly based on the formulas for $\alpha$ and $r$ in the $k$-th step which are also given on wikipedia:
\begin{align*}
 \alpha &= -\text{sgn}(a_{k+1,k})\sqrt{\sum_{j=2}^n a_{jk}^2} \\
 r &= \sqrt{\frac 1 2 \alpha^2 - \frac 1 2 \alpha a_{k+1,k}} \\
w_1 &= ... = w_k = 0 \\
w_{k+1} &= \frac{a_{k+1,k} - \alpha}{2r} \\
w_j &= \frac{a_{jk}}{2r} \qquad \qquad j = k+2,k+3,...,n \\
\end{align*}
From these, the $k$-th Householder reflector is constructed by $$P = I - 2ww^t$$ and multiplied to A from both sides.
However, my main problem is that I want to translate the algorithm from Burden to an algorithm that also works for the complex (hermitian) case. But I'm struggling immensly with the actual derivation of $\alpha$ and $r$ for complex valued matrices - from there I may be able to derive a correct algorithm which circumvents the matrix multiplication $PAP$.
This is where I stand (k = 1):
To find the correct entries of $w$, we wirst define $\hat{w} = (w_2, w_3, ..., w_n)^t$ and $\hat{y} = (a_{21}, ..., a_{n1})^t$. We want that our householder reflector $P$ zeros out all entries of the first column of $A$ except the first two. This essentially translates to:
\begin{equation}
\hat{P}\hat{y} = (I_{n-1} - 2\hat{w}\hat{w}^H)\hat{y} = \hat{y} - 2 (\hat{w}^H\hat{y})\hat{w} \overset{!}{=} (\alpha, 0,..., 0)^t
\end{equation}
where $(\cdot)^H$ denotes the conjugate transpose and $\hat{P} = I_{n-1} - 2\hat{w}\hat{w}^H$ is the householder reflector in $\mathbb{C}^{n-1}$.
Setting $r = \hat{w}^H \hat{y}$ we get
\begin{align}
2rw_2 &= a_{21} - \alpha \\
2rw_j &= a_{j1} 
\end{align}
for $j = 3,...,n$.
Taking the absolute value on both sides of the equations and adding them yields:
\begin{equation}
\vert 2r \vert^2 \sum_{j = 2}^n \vert w_j \vert ^2 = \vert a_{21} - \alpha \vert^2 + \sum_{j = 3}^n \vert a_{j1} \vert^2
\end{equation}
Since $a_{11}$ must be left unchanged, we have $w_1$ = 0 and by postulating $w^Hw = 1$, we get
\begin{equation}
4\vert r \vert^2 = \sum_{j = 3}^n \vert a_{j1} \vert^2 + \vert a_{21} - \alpha \vert^2
\end{equation}
Now using $P$ being unitary and $\alpha$ being real (we want the algorithm to yield a real tridiagonal matrix), we get
\begin{equation}
\alpha^2 = (\alpha, 0,...,0)(\alpha,0,...,0)^H = (\hat{P}\hat{y})^H\hat{P}\hat{y} = \hat{y}^H \hat{P}^H\hat{P}\hat{y} = \hat{y}^H\hat{y} = \sum_{j=2}^n a_{j1} \overline{a}_{j1} = \sum_{j=2}^n \vert a_{j1} \vert^2
\end{equation}
Now Burden uses the binomial formula to get a nice equation for $2r^2$, but since $a_{21}$ is complex, I can't do the same simplification. Furthermore, even if I did, he later chooses $\alpha$ depending on the sign of $a_{21}$ which also probably isn'T senseful when $a_{21}$ is complex. I suspect the phase of $a_{21}$ is involved in this, but I can't really put my finger on it.
Does anyone have any ideas how to proceed from this point or how to tackle the problem from a different angle? The main problem is that my Householder algorithm is way too slow since the matrix $P$ is initialised and multiplied by $A$ (even though I only let it act on the relevant columns).

See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4953662/a-efficient-algorithm-for-the-householder-transformation-of-a-hermitian-matrix

@BrianBorchers I'm aware of this post, but as I wrote I'm interested in a algorithm that explicitly avoids explicit matrix multiplication - something like the algorithm which is given in the book.

If $P=(I-2uu^{H})$, then $Px=x-2(u^{H}x)u$.  You never have to explicitly form the $P$ matrix.

@BrianBorchers I'm still kind of stumped. Sure I can calculate $Px = x - 2(u^Hx)u$ for the corresponding $k$th column vector I want to set to zero, but: $\textbf{a)}$ How can I now let P act efficiently on the other $k+1,...,n$ column vectors and $\textbf{b)}$ How can I now realize the multiplication from the right $T*P$? I obviously want to do as little as possbile of operations - using that I know what entries are set to zero and what are left unchanged - but I can't get much better than actually initializing P and letting it act on the corresponding rows and columns.

@BrianBorchers Okay, I can definitely for each relevant column just calculate the product as you said, so in the k-th step we have $PT(k+1:n,j) = T(k+1:n,j) - 2(u^H T(k+1:n,j)u$ for $j \in {k+1,...,n}$ (The k-th column can be set to zero from k+2:n and the k+1-th entry is just the norm of the column).  But how would I implement the multiplication from the right after that? I can't find a better idea than just calculating: $T(k+1:n,k+1:n) = T(k+1:n,k+1:n)(I_{n-k} - 2uu^H)$ which is matrix multiplication I wanted to avoid.

It is similar, just multiply A time u and then multiply by u^H.
